# Should users comment or flag posts when personal information could be disclosed?

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121672/what-to-do-with-1-000-000-00-for-31-2-months) came up in my feed. The users username appears to be a real name. The user is probably based in the US. The user is disclosing that they likely have a million dollars in a liquid account.

Should this post be flagged or should a comment be posted to let users like this know they can change their user name and should consider changing it to a pseudonym to avoid inadvertently disclosing private financial information?

I see another user commented to this effect. Is there specific help entry to advise new users on how to change their username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best initial approach is to point out the issue and let the user take whatever action they think appropriate. There's no specific help entry on changing username that I can see, but there is this [meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site). The user can also be told how to flag posts (there's a [help entry for that](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) if they need help.

If you see a particularly serious case, or a user wanting to do something but not sure how, do flag it yourself with a custom reason. We'd generally be reluctant to do much without the user asking though.